# C# How to correctly set assembly title for Windows 8 Task Manager?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-assembly, taskmanager

I've set the title & assembly info of my C# Winforms executable as follow:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Widgets Galore")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Widgets Inc")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Widgets Galore")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © Widgets Inc 2012")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

...

MainForm.Text = "Widgets Galore by Widgets Incorporated";

...

// Compiles to: widgets.app.exe
```

In Windows 7 Task Manager, it correctly shows the process as the main form title:

```
"Widgets Galore by Widgets Incorporated"
```

However in Windows 8 Task Manager, it incorrectly shows the executable name, with a sub item:

```
"widgets.app"
    |--"Widgets Galore by Widgets Incorporated".
```

I see plenty of other applications listed with a friendly name in the Windows 8 Task Manager, and would like to see my app do the same.

How can I force W8 to do a friendly name for my app?

-Brendan

Comment: It uses the [AssemblyTitle] attribute.  Hard to reconcile that with your question.  Isolate this by first using a dummy Winforms project. Look for a problem with a custom .res file next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through trial and error I found that Windows 8 Task Manager shows the exe name regardless of [AssemblyTitle], IF your file is not digitally signed. I assume this is a security measure. Solution: digitally sign.