# Change name of my program in Task Manager

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, taskmanager

I Start a Demo Project just for testing.

But on this demo work good and I just tried to create a release from it.
The problem, when I tried to start it (On debug mod for example) I see a process name  like

[image: http://prntscr.com/ikb4kk]

(in the red circle)

I also change the properties of my project like this.

[image: http://prntscr.com/ikb578]

Someone have any solution to do this "DataBaseAccessValidator" to be my name in Task Manager?

To change my solution and my directory name did not work for my problem.

[image: http://prntscr.com/ikbaac]

Comment: I have a big program... I don't know which part is relevant...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper way to rename solution (and directories) in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043618/proper-way-to-rename-solution-and-directories-in-visual-studio)

Comment: I tried it... I changed my directory and my solution
http://prntscr.com/ikbaac

Comment: My suggestion: Follow the steps of the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19844531/4934172) in the link above, make sure you use the same name for everything, and you should be good to go.

Comment: @hedo, You should change `Assembly Information Title`...

Comment: @Johnny you mean 
"Right click on your project -> select Applicattion Tab -> change assembly name"?

If yes, I did so, not work for me.. :(

Comment: There is a button labelled "Assembly Information" - try clicking on that - top line is "Title". You could also try programmatically changing the application title in your code.

Comment: Not assembly name, you have assembly information, open it and then change the Title. @PaulF exactly ;) Look at your second screenshot, there is a button...

Comment: @PaulF  Thanks, Its solved my problem

Comment: @Johnny Thanks, Its solved my problem

Comment: Nice, I will post the answer then :)

Comment: PaulF & Johnny are right. Just to elaborate, The Task Manager of Windows 10 displays two different names: 1) In the Processes tab, it displays the `Title`. 2) In the Details tab, it displays the `Assembly Name`. However, whenever you want to rename your solution/project, you should do it properly to avoid unexpected behavior, and that's why I referred to the question above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# How to correctly set assembly title for Windows 8 Task Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647314/c-sharp-how-to-correctly-set-assembly-title-for-windows-8-task-manager)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should change the `Title` within the `Assembly Information`.

Within the `Application Properties` page there is a button `Assembly Information`, open it and change the `Title`. See the following links:

[Application Properties](http://prntscr.com/ikb578) then [Assembly Information](https://prnt.sc/ikbo76)

Comment: Yes, that's the way to change the assembly name and title. But sometime it will not reflect after changing because windows adds a registry in CURRENT_USER in registry. so go to regedit and find your old assembly name. After deleting it will reflect new name in task manager and taskbar.

Answer (score -4):

The name that appear in Task Manager is the name to your executable program. You can change it, by using the properties of your project.

```
Right click on your project -> select Applicattion Tab -> change assembly name.
```

Comment: I did it. I showed it in the second link http://prntscr.com/ikb578... did not work.

Comment: did you also change the project name by right clicking on project from solution explorer and selecting rename option?

Comment: I have created a copy of my original project and change his directory name by using Windows GUI by rename option...
I did rename my solution by VisualStudio GUI by right click on my project On VisualStudio and Rename...

Comment: not the solution, the project. did you rename the project from solution explorer?